# How to ping default gateway from a pc?

Tags: routing, gns3

[image: Network map]

How can I ping the default gateway from PC2?
I have tried `IP <address> [/<mask>] [<gateway>]` command for R1, but is says "not in subnet".

And when I tried the same command for R3, it works but I still can't ping R1 and I don't know why.

Comment: R1 R2  and R3 can ping each other perfectly .does this means that the default route for each router is being set already?

Comment: Welcome to NE, we hope you will both contribute to and learn from this community. You could improve your question by editing it to add more details. You may find our [Question Checklist](http://meta.networkengineering.stackexchange.com/q/292/33) helpful when editing your question. For example: configuration from at least your routers, routing tables from same, etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

- PC2 needs a route for 144.120.8.1 (or default route) that points at R3
- R3 needs a route for 144.120.8.1 (or default route) that points at R2
- R2 needs a route for PC2 (or default route) that points at R3
- R1 needs a route for PC2 (or default route) that points at R2

Check the routing tables on these devices to confirm these routes exist.

Comment: thanks so much sir ill try apply this one my work and see if it work..

Comment: this is the routing table for R2   i notice that the gateway is ot set..do i have to set it?                                      Gateway of last resort is not set

     144.120.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 3 masks
R       144.120.11.128/25 [120/1] via 144.120.9.2, 00:00:13, FastEthernet0/1
C       144.120.8.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       144.120.9.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
R       144.120.10.0/24 [120/1] via 144.120.9.2, 00:00:13, FastEthernet0/1
R       144.120.11.0/25 [120/1] via 144.120.9.2, 00:00:13, FastEthernet0/1

Comment: You don't need a default gateway no.  But R2 does need a route to PC2 via R3.  This appears to be either your .10.0/24 or your .11.0/24?  It is unclear from the diagram the subnets for PC1/2/3.  In any case, your next step after verify the routes is to trace a ping and see where it is getting dropped (usually done with simultaneous tcpdumps on each device in the chain)

Comment: ohh ok ok thanks..am working on ip route now.. thanks so much for helping me sir.

Comment: do i need to close the ip route command with a no shoutdown or a no auto-summary command or i just exit after doing the ip route?

Comment: That sounds possibly device specific, I'm not sure.   Of course, you'll want to make the route changes persistent eventually once you get the connectivity how you like.  And you'll want to make them live immediately since you are testing as you make your modifications.

Comment: ok ive manage to ip route for R2 to PC2 using the link on R3....now i want to ip route from PC2 to R1 using the link on R3 .i know i have to use a local interface in the ip route, but am not sure whats the interface for PC2. will it be the same as the interface on 11.0/24 ? on link R3?

Comment: i did the ip route from pc2 to R1 like this         :  ip route 144.120.8.0 255.255.255.252 f1/0
Invalid options
but is give invalid options...this is giving me headache .hh..:).i wont give up.

Comment: What's R3's IP that's on the same subnet as PC2?  That should be the "via" for your 144.120.8.0 route.

Comment: Gateway of last resort is not set

     144.120.0.0/16 is variably subnetted, 5 subnets, 3 masks
C       144.120.11.128/25 is directly connected, FastEthernet2/0
R       144.120.8.0/30 [120/1] via 144.120.9.1, 00:00:18, FastEthernet0/1
C       144.120.9.0/30 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/1
C       144.120.10.0/24 is directly connected, FastEthernet0/0
C       144.120.11.0/25 is directly connected, FastEthernet1/0
 thats the ip route for R3.. for some reason it does not say via 144.120.8.0..

Comment: the ip for R3 is 144.120.11.2 ..so you mean that i should ip route from 144.120.8.1 to 144.120.11.2  via 144.120.11.0?

Comment: from PC2 am able to ping R2 but i just cant continue ping to R1 (default gateway) what should i do from this point

Answer (score 0):

Configure a [host route on your PC](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/sag_tcpip_pro_addstaticroute.mspx?mfr=true) telling it that the PC's default gateway is R3.